# How to view an image/pdf in browser and show download dialogue after it is loaded in the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, download

I'd like to have a link that open an image/pdf in the browser and after it is loaded, show a option dialogue to download it. Is it possible?

my current anchor:

```
echo "<a href='".base_url()."assets/uploads/".$record->file_upload.".".substr($record->original_name, -3)."' id='txt_upl' download>";
echo $record->original_name;
echo "</a>";
```

Comment: firefox and chrome automatically show download option after showing the pdf in the browser. but you have to remove `download` attribute from the `<a>` tag. If `download` is there, browsers will not display it and will prompt for download.

Answer (score 0):

I found this PDF.js libary, maybe this is what you're looking for:

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a javascript library for parsing and rendering PDFs. You can use [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) for this purpose.

Outline of what you need to do:

- add pdf.js library at the start of your page
- keep the pdf download link in the page but make it hidden
- load and render the pdf using pdf.js after passing the pdf URL to it.
- pdf.js returns [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can do extra stuff after it finishes loading or rendering the pdf.
- Now you unhide the download link.

I gave an example of how to use pdf.js and how it returns promises (notice the console logs after clicking 'run code snippet')

I have also added a comment in JS code where you may add the extra code to unhide the download link.

```js
var url = '//cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf';
//load the pdf
var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  //load the page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    var scale = .5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered. changing the visibility of download link');
      //======================================================================
      //SO NOW THE PDF IS LOADED AND RENDERED. HERE YOU NEED TO ADD EXTRA JAVASCRIPT CODE TO SHOW THE DOWNLOAD LINK
      document.getElementById("dlink").style.visibility = "visible";
      //======================================================================
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
}
#dlink {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<a href="//cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf" id="dlink" download>Download</a>
```